# Does SoundTouch use C on Windows and C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, soundtouch

I'm trying to integrate SoundTouch (https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) as a shared library into a cross-platform Qt app.  The version in the Ubuntu repos seems to provide a C++ interface like this:

```cpp
this->soundTouchHandle = new SoundTouch();
this->soundTouchHandle->setSampleRate(44100);
this->soundTouchHandle->setChannels(2);

this->soundTouchHandle->setSetting(SETTING_USE_AA_FILTER, 1);
this->soundTouchHandle->setPitch(this->pitchScalingFactor);
```

But it seems like the normal way to use it on Windows is through the SoundTouchDLL C wrapper (which provides the `__cdecl` exports):

```c
this->soundTouchHandle = soundtouch_createInstance();
soundtouch_setSampleRate(this->soundTouchHandle, 44100);
soundtouch_setChannels(this->soundTouchHandle, 2);

soundtouch_setSetting(this->soundTouchHandle, SETTING_USE_AA_FILTER, 1);
soundtouch_setPitch(this->soundTouchHandle, this->pitchScalingFactor);
```

If I understand correctly, Linux doesn't need the `__cdecl` annotations, the C-based SoundTouchDLL interface is specifically for windows.  SoundTouchDLL.h clearly contains windows-specific code (e.g. `#include <windows.h>`).  On the other hand, the core C++ SoundTouch library doesn't include annotations for exporting any symbols with `__cdecl`, so it can't be used as a shared library (DLL) on Windows, the C interface is required.

Have I understood this correctly?  Is it really normal to use the C API for SoundTouch on Windows, but use the C++ API on Linux?  Is there any way to use the same API on both platforms (preferably without having to modify SoundTouch)?

Comment: Have you tried calling the C API functions on Linux?

Comment: Yes, in a manner of speaking.  If you include the SoundTouchDLL.h file with the C interface on Linux, you get `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token` on every line that uses `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)`.

Comment: I guess I could create my own linux-specific C wrapper file, but that's exactly the sort of thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I can get it to compile on Linux if I add a few `#ifdef`s to remove platform-specific annotations like `__cdecl`.  I'll wait in hope for better answers (surely I'm not the only one with this problem??).

For now I'm going to fork it on GitHub and update the C interface.  I'll post a link back here with my changes.

Comment: After about a day of effort, I managed to iron out a version of the C API that works on both Windows (MSVC) and Linux (GCC).

https://github.com/unyieldinggrace/SoundTouch